# Why applying functions using the pair "dot" notation can be a syntax error in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

In Racket, the following form of defining functions is supported:

```rkt
(define (plus1 . x) (+ x 1))
(define (sum-all . l) (apply + l))
```

`sum-all` function can then be used as follows:

```rkt
(sum-all 1 2 3)     ; => 6
(sum-all . (1 2 3)) ; => 6
```

However, this does not work for `plus1`:

```rkt
(plus1 . 0) ; bad syntax error
```

Similarly,

```rkt
(define (sum-two a . b) (+ a b))
(sum-two 1 . 2) ; bad syntax error
```

Why is this syntax not allowed?

Comment: There is a [related question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/255291/) already, but it does not seem equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

An application form needs to be of the form of a proper list, which `(sum-two 1 . 2)` is not.
On the other hand, `(sum-two 1 2 . ())` is.

In the definition of `(plus1 . x)`, `x` is intended to be a list in `plus1`'s body.
Indeed, applying `plus1` to any argument will result in a run-time error.

Comment: Why not to allow an arbitrary tree of arguments, like `(define (f (a . b) . (c . d)) (+ a b c d))`?

Comment: What's a use case of that? Could you elaborate more? The purpose of allowing `rest` parameters is to allow defining multiple-arity functions, which is more or less for syntactic convenience. It is not obvious that allowing parameters of an arbitrary tree shape as such would buy us anything worth the complexity.

Comment: I thought that this would *reduce* the complexity by treating all tree shapes uniformly, but it is quite possible i am missing some reason why this would not work.

Comment: What you're looking for is [`match-define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=match-define#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) from the pattern-matching library.

Answer (score 2):

Within a `define` form, `(define (func . args) body)` means that whatever arguments you give to `func`, they are to be put into a single list, named `args`.

However, when you're *calling* that function, calling it as `(func . 1)` doesn't mean anything at all. That's why it's a syntax error.